# How to search for multiple ObjectIds using MongoDB Atlas Search

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

I have documents in a MongoDB collection that reference ObjectIds in a different collection. For example, my Orders collection has documents with a CustomerId.

Using MongoDB Atlas search, I've defined an index that allows me to search the CustomerId field with this syntax:

```
{
  "index": "Orders",
  "equals": {
    "path": "CustomerId"
    "value": new ObjectId("5m5....")
  }
}
```

(The above snippet is from the $search stage of my aggregation pipeline.)

But now I need to perform an OR search using multiple customer Ids. Unfortunately, I can't just specify an array of ObjectIds when using the `equals` operator. https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/atlas-search/equals/

What are my options for searching a MongoDB Atlas Search index with multiple ObjectIds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a compound query with a `should` clause and minimumShouldMatch set to 1 - https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/atlas-search/compound/.

Comment: I had the same idea! Using a `should` clause improves the scores of documents containing my target CustomerIds, but it doesn't prevent other documents from appearing within my results. Ideally, I'd want to do this within the `must` or `filter` clauses.

Comment: Does using "minimumShouldMatch" set to 1 help? (It's mentioned in the same help page)

Comment: It does... as long as I never need to add a filter on a different field into the `should` array. It meets my current use case, though.

Comment: You can nest compound queries within a compound query. So you can have two compounds with shoulds inside a must, both of them with their own minimumShouldOccur. This would allow you to filter separately.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that compound queries could nest like that. In that case, this is definitely the best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to follow the `$search` stage with a `$match` stage. Then you can use the `$in` operator to search for multiple ObjectIds. Note that this approach has performance implications, as described here:

https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/atlas-search/performance/#-match-aggregation-stage-usage

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me using @Petko's suggestion

```
[{
"$search": {
  "index": "Orders",
  "compound": {
    "should": [
      {
        "equals": {
          "path": "CustomerId",
          "value": {"$oid": "62a..."}
        }
      },
      {
        "equals": {
          "path": "CustomerId",
          "value": {"$oid": "62a..."}
        }
      },
      {
        "equals": {
          "path": "CustomerId",
          "value": {"$oid": "62a..."}
        }
      }
    ],
    "minimumShouldMatch": 1
  }
}
```

}
]